# convert quarter number to month name in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to convert quarter number to month name in sql server? 
like :

```
1: Jan
2: Apr
3: Jul
4: Oct
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use arithmetic and `datename()`:

```
select datename(month, dateadd(month, 3 * @q - 3, '2019-01-01'))
```

`@q` a variable that represents the quarter that you want to convert to a month name.

Comment: what if there's no exact date?  And what is your @q stands for?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @getmonth   INT
DECLARE @datestring VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE    @input      VARCHAR(20)

SET @input = 'Jan'

SET @datestring = @input + ' 1 2019'

SET @getmonth = MONTH(CAST(@datestring AS DATETIME))

SELECT @getmonth
```

Comment: it doesn't work when i turn 'Jan' to 'May' and turn '1 2019' to '5 2019', the output should be 2 instead of 5. Please check.